# Using explained variance to stop model training early, like StopTrainingOnRewardThreshold

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to learn Python by building an RL Forex trading bot using TensorFlow and StableBaselines3. I want to stop the training of my model early, based on a combination of the built-in StopTrainingOnRewardThreshold callback and the explained variance of the model during training.

My training is set up as follows:

```py
"""Train Model"""
################################################################
if user_action == 2:
    env_maker = lambda: gym.make('forex-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(15, 250), window_size=5)
    env = DummyVecEnv([env_maker])
    model = A2C('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1)
    callback_on_best = CustomCallback(explained_variance=0.7, reward_threshold=300, verbose=1)
    eval_callback = EvalCallback(env, callback_on_new_best=callback_on_best, verbose=1)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=1000000, callback=callback_on_best)
    model.save("A2C_trading_Ai")
    while True:
        user_action_after_train = int(input("\n===============================================\n"
                                            "Training Complete! Evaluate model now?\n"
                                            "\t1 = Yes\n"
                                            "\t2 = No\n\n"
                                            "Response = \t\t"))
        if user_action_after_train != 1 and user_action != 2:
            print("Invalid Input!\n")
        elif user_action_after_train == 1:
            user_action = 3
            print("===============================================\n")
            break
        else:
            break
################################################################
```

I am struggling to retrieve the explained variance for each step from the model during training. I used the StopTrainingOnRewardThreshold source code and edited it as follows:

```py
"""Custom Callback for Model Training"""
################################################################
class CustomCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, explained_variance: float, reward_threshold: float, verbose: int = 0):
        super().__init__(verbose=verbose)
        self.explained_variance = explained_variance
        self.reward_threshold = reward_threshold

    def _on_step(self) -> bool:
        assert self.parent is not None, \
            "``StopTrainingOnMinimumReward`` callback must be used " "with an ``EvalCallback``"
        # Convert np.bool_ to bool, otherwise callback() is False won't work
        continue_training = bool(self.parent.explained_variance < self.explained_variance and
                                 self.parent.best_mean_reward < self.reward_threshold)
        if self.verbose >= 1 and not continue_training:
            print(
                f"Stopping training because the mean explained variance {self.parent.explained_variance:.2f} "
                f"and the mean reward {self.parent.best_mean_reward:.2f}"
                f" are above the thresholds {self.explained_variance} and {self.best_mean_reward}"
            )
        return continue_training
################################################################
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to solve this ?

Comment: Are u able to solve ?

Comment: I suspect returning true or false maps to either continuing or stopping. 

What is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: How is the [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)-generated answer working for you? (Not a rhetorical question)

Comment: OK, Tian van Wyk has left the building; *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Comment: @user1047873: Perhaps this wasn't the kind of attention wished for?

Comment: Is it a viable option to spam bounty questions with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)-generated answers? Will it be awarded by default? What is the mechanism?

Comment: Hi, have you managed to implement the desired callback?